# Why is a JSSE provider used in the following situation?

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I saw this example - [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124) - of using javamail to send an email and i noticed the manual setting of a JSSE provider.
What is the point of using JSSE in the context of sending mail without user interaction on android? ( i never used JSSE related code when sending email via smtps while coding for JVM.  ). What are the consequences of  removing the bits of code related to `JSSEProvider` ? I have the feeling i may not connect to a mail server using `imaps` or `smtps`. Is that the case? There is some code  for android that relies on javamail to send mail, without explicitly using/referencing JSSE related stuff. The code is untested by me but the majority of commenters agrees that it works as advertised, which adds to my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the referenced code includes several [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  I don't know why the JSSE provider would be required, but perhaps fixing those mistakes will remove the need for it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.Funny thing that the best rated and also accepted answer still has those mistakes. I would have expected someone on SO to have modified the code in that answer by now .

Comment: are those common JavaMail mistakes still mistakes for JavaMail 1.4.3 ?I'm referring to the bullet regarding socketFactory... I ask because javamail for android was last updated in 2009

Comment: Android isn't Java so it could be doing something weird, but JavaMail 1.4.3 on Java SE doesn't need to set a socket factory to use SSL.

Answer (score 0):

From the constructor of the class

```
public JSSEProvider() {
    super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");

    put("SSLContext.SSL", SSLContextImpl.class.getName());
    put("SSLContext.SSLv3", SSLContextImpl.class.getName());
    put("SSLContext.TLS", SSLContextImpl.class.getName());
    put("SSLContext.TLSv1", SSLContextImpl.class.getName());

    put("KeyManagerFactory.X509", KeyManagerFactoryImpl.class.getName());
    put("TrustManagerFactory.X509", TrustManagerFactoryImpl.class.getName());
    put("KeyStore.AndroidCAStore", TrustedCertificateKeyStoreSpi.class.getName());
}
```

JSSEProvider is used to link the modified versions of SSLContext, KeyManagerFactory for X509, TrustManagerFactory for X509 and the AndroidCAstore. Hence, you will not be able to remove if it was meant for Android.